# Who reads `/etc/default/keyboard`?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, configuration, xkb, evdev

And I do not care about the console here (I care about X11)...

I see in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` that my X-server picks up `xkb_rules evdev` from somewhere I can’t find.

It also seems to take `xkb_model` and `xkb_layout` from the config file `/etc/default/keyboard`. And I’m asking myself, is that hardcoded in X or the evdev driver?? The man-pages don’t mention that file, as usual... :-(

So, where is the code that connects that file to X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `/lib/udev/rules.d/64-xorg-xkb.rules` is responsible to put it in the udev database. I guess the evdev driver picks it up from there. (Udev maintains an in-memory(?) database, and the driver reads the entries related to “input”.)

The application of the rules “evdev” is probably hardcoded in that driver. (I.e. `xkb_model` and `xkb_layout` is from udev, but `xkb_rules` hardcoded, I believe.)

Comment: Excuse me Robert, but I couldn't understand what you mean in second paragraph "“evdev” is probably hardcoded in that driver"? what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @user.dz XKB (if it’s highest level is used) is driven by rules, model, layout, variant and option, with the rules being the entry point. `xkb_rules=evdev` as default is probably hardcoded in the evdev driver. (If not, where does it come from?) `xkb_rules` could also be `xorg` or `xfree86`, for example.